# Counting between 2 words

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have something similar to the following table:

| Jan|
| 5  |
| 10 |
| 20 |
| 50 |
| Mar|
|  1 |
| 101|
|  6 |
I need come function in which will count the value between Jan and Mar.
Result:4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depending on what you need, I can see a few possibilities.

1) If you know exactly where "Jan" (say, A1) and "Mar" (say, A6) will be, you can just use `=COUNT(A2:A5)`. This is useful when you know where your months will be.

2) If you don't know exactly where "Jan" and "Mar" will be, you need to use a variation of Match which might look like `=MATCH("Jan", A:A, 0)` in B1 and then `=MATCH("Mar", A:A, 0)` in C1. This will give you the row number of "Jan" and "Mar", which you can then plug back in to `=COUNT()`.

A sample formula to count would look like this:

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("A"&B1):INDIRECT("A"&C1))-2
```

The -2 is to account for the fact that you're including those rows.

Comment: Thanks for the help, im using your second method but had another question now.  I get the row values or "Jan" and "Mar" but then when I plug it into Count, I get just get 2.  Is there something else I have to add in the Count function to make this work?

Comment: Yeah, it's a little convoluted from there. First of all, the match is only giving you a row value. Now you have to use that row value indirectly. This looks like `INDIRECT("A"&B1)` if you want to get "A1" for example (if "Jan" is in row 1). This attaches the row from B1 to the letter "A". You also have to remember that if you use this method, you will get A1:A6, which is too many rows because it includes your original rows! I will edit in a formula to my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for INDIRECT:

```
=MATCH("Mar",A:A,0)-MATCH("Jan",A:A,0)-1
```

(except perhaps to qualify an answer as *complex*, per [excel] tag, as more than a single function).